# How to open “Other User's Folder” from VSTO Add-in for Microsoft Outloook?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

Is it possible to open *Other User's Folder* from VSTO Add-in in MS Outloook?

thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Call `Application.CreateRecipient`, then pass the returned `Recipient` object to `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder`.